# Error on Nested IF ";" expected but "identifier GANJIL" found

Tags: pascal

I got an error messages saying : `Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier GANJIL" found`. So I decided to place " ; " at the error line(commented as error 1). Now second error message shows up, saying : `Fatal Syntax error, ";" expected but "ELSE" found` at another line. (commented as "Error 2")
I've been looking for the solution through google and no help.
thanks before.

```
program s01;
Var 
    x,t,i,counter,genap,ganjil:integer;
begin
    write('Masukkan nilai x :'); readln(x);
    for i:=1 to x do
    begin
        write('case ',i,' :'); readln(t);
        genap  := 1;
        ganjil := 1;
        for counter:=0 to (t+2) do
        begin
            if counter=t+2 then
                write(ganjil)
        else
            write(ganjil,'') //Error 1
            ganjil := ganjil+2
        else
            if counter=t-1 then //Error 2
                    write(genap);
            else
                    begin
                        write(genap,'');
                        genap := genap+2;
                    end;    
        end;
        writeln();
    end;
Readln();            
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

The second else does not make sense. The construct is if..then[..else], iow only one else per if.

Also the semicolon before write(genap) is probably not what you want.

And the indentation is strange.(why are write(ganjil,'') and ganjil:=ganjil+2; on the same level?).

Besides making it easier for yourself, proper indentation is also a clue to use if you understood it or not.

Comment: I am sorry for the indetation because of the automatic indetation in my IDE, i use Charm Pascal and it gave me an auto complete feature :(